# How to replicate this bottom with shadow, highlight effect and a non-flat color?

Tags: css, html

[af http://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/62862049/Screenshots/pf.png](http://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/62862049/Screenshots/pf.png)

I've managed to replicate it partially: I've got a bottom with rounded, solid border, solid colored background. I'm stuck on the effects: the highlight on top - the way the background color is not uniform - and the text and the bottom itself seems to have a shadow. So, I've used so far: `border, border-radius, background-color`. How are those done?

Comment: You should give us an example of what you're using, for example with jsfiddle.

Answer (score 3):

Something like : http://jsfiddle.net/rEHSL/

Have a look at the CSS3 `box-shadow` property.

The CSS for the background gradient is from - http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

**CSS:**

```
#test { color:#fff; font-size:18px; text-align:center; width:300px; height:100px; background:orange;


/* Inner and Outer shadows */
-webkit-box-shadow:  inset 0px 0px 2px 2px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8),
0px 0px 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);

box-shadow:  inset 0px 0px 2px 2px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8),
0px 0px 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);

/* rounded corners */
-webkit-border-radius: 15px;
border-radius: 15px;

/* graident bg */
background: rgb(255,175,75); /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(255,175,75,1) 0%, rgba(255,146,10,1) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(255,175,75,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(255,146,10,1))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(255,175,75,1) 0%,rgba(255,146,10,1) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(255,175,75,1) 0%,rgba(255,146,10,1) 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(255,175,75,1) 0%,rgba(255,146,10,1) 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(255,175,75,1) 0%,rgba(255,146,10,1) 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffaf4b', endColorstr='#ff920a',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
```